# AutoHotKeys Web Input Fields

Tags: autohotkey

I use an AutoHotKet script to login to variuos sites by moving the mouse to the userid and password fields and entering my information.  Is there a function that returns information obout web page input fields?  I didn't see anything like this in the docs.

Regard amd thanks in advance,
Rock

Comment: Multiple browser plugins already has this feature, and offers better security. Any reason why you aren't just using lastpass or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you use IE, COM is the way to go

Tut http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/64563-basic-ahk-l-com-tutorial-for-webpages/

Little vid of using COM to login to a site http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lgTc9hBMs8

Hope it helps